# Build python's gevent in outer Docker image

Tags: python, docker, gevent, alpine-linux

This dockerfile will obviously not work:

```
FROM python:3.7.0-alpine

RUN pip install gevent
```

since there is no compiler in alpine.

Is it possible to install it in a different docker image and then copy it to my image?

In other words, can i achieve that by replacing `<???>` with something?

```
FROM python:3.7.0-streach as base

RUN pip install gevent

FROM python:3.7.0-alpine

COPY --from=base <???>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those finding this a year later, this should work:

```
FROM python:3.7.0-stretch as base

RUN apk add build-base
RUN mkdir /install
RUN pip install --install-option="--prefix=/install" gevent

FROM python:3.7.0-alpine

COPY --from=base /install /usr/local
```

Answer (score 0):

Alpine Linux has the `build-base` that provides a convenient way to install a compiler and other build tools. You'll want to install `libffi-dev` and other packages that provide headers as well.

Your intended approach to copy `gevent` from a Debian-based container to an Alpine-based one, will not work as the latter uses `musl`, not `libc`. Have a look at `apk`'s `--virtual` option to easily un-/install build dependencies.

As far as I can tell, due to ABI changes `gevent` (or certain versions of it) do not compile against CPython 3.7 (yet).

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: Okay, the answer to your questions is: No.